# Mongodb "in" query for pattern search using Spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to get a list of all persons who have some keywords in their hobbies (for example hockey - case insensitive).

The Java class corresponding to my Mongo collection is

```
class Person {
 String name;
 List<String> hobbies;
}
```

Before saving this document in Mongo collection, I am converting each of the hobby to lowercase.

Per https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/, such queries are supported using Mongo shell and I am able to get the data using the below command

```
db.person.find({"hobbies":{$in:[/hockey/]}})
```

However using the Spring Mongodb (3.2.4), I am not getting the data using code snippet below

```
Criteria.where("hobbies").in("/"+ "Hockey".toLowerCase() +"/");
```

Would like to know if there is a way to get the data using Spring library?

Answer (score 0):

Criteria.where("hobbies").regex("Hockey".toLowerCase(),"i") solved the issue